# Field Subclass Accessing - Best Way Possible

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, field, getter

So I've run into a bit of a problem dealing with preferences in a program. Considering the amount of times this will be used, having a single method would be best. A getter for each variable could potentially lead to a substantially larger file.

(5 fields * 200 to 300 classes = lots of wasted space)

**I am trying to figure out how to access a Field with a defined and constant name from a subclass.**

The super class is abstract, defined in a list and I have full access to it. This is the class where I would like the getter for the field to be in.

The way I would like it to work would be something like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Test {

    public Test() {
        final B b = new B();
        final C c = new C();
        System.out.println(b.getFoo());
        System.out.println(c.getFoo());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public class A {

        public String getFoo() {
            try {
                Field f = this.getClass().getField("FOO");
                f.setAccessible(true);
                return (String) f.get(null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

    }

    public class B extends A {

        private static final String FOO = "$HOME.DIR/lib/res/image1.png";

    }

    public class C extends A {

        private static final String FOO = "$HOME.DIR/lib/res/image2.png";

    }

}
```

Expectedly, that did not work. The class `A` does not contain the field 'FOO'. Ideally, if it had worked I would have expected it to print out:

> $HOME.DIR/lib/res/image1.png
>   $HOME.DIR/lib/res/image2.png

The ways I have (so far) seen that this would be possible:

1. Reflection
2. Using a Getter - **Would like to avoid**
3. Using annotations

Using annotations was one way I could see it being possible, yet I generally do not like the overall concept of them, but if it is the only way I would of course accept it.

Thank you for reading this, hopefully you can provide insight.

Comment: I'm wondering why it's easier in your mind to put `private static final String FOO = "$HOME.DIR/lib/res/image2.png";` in the subclass than to put `public String getFOO() { return "$HOME.DIR/lib/res/image2.png"}` when both are about the same length in characters and both can be done with a cut/paste/type in all 200-300 subclasses. (You could use a property file with all the strings indexed by the name of the class, like `B=$HOME.DIR/lib/res/image2.png` and a getFoo() method in A.)

Comment: This is both to learn from, expand on (open API hopefully) and to truly just de-clutter. I really only put `private static final` in front for demonstration purposes, but those wouldn't be needed at all. It would only ever have one instance, so no need to only maintain one variable like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you describe your higher level problem in more detail, since it sounds like there may be some design changes that you could make to alleviate this issue.  Accessing the fields of a subclass form a parent class via reflection just seems like a bad idea in general.

However, with that said, you need to use `getDeclaredField` instead of `getField` in order to access a private field by reflection.

E.g.

```
public String getFoo() {
        try {
            Field f = this.getClass().getDeclaredField("FOO");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            return (String) f.get(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: Even changed from static and using getDeclaredField it failed, sadly. As I pointed out in the above class, the final revision for the data types could come down to: `String foo = "this";`

Comment: The above will work with static.  If using non-static then you need to pass in the instance to f.get instead of null.

Comment: @Legend, I changed your code above to just have the getDeclaredField and it worked just fine...

Comment: @Legend, your code above does not require this, but yes, if you want to access non-static things you need to specify what instance to use, and this is the one to pass in for your case.

Comment: This should _really_ be treated as the very last resort. Possibly when editing the existing classes is _absolutely_ not possible. Reflection is powerful but notoriously slow and should be used judiciously. Another issue with it is that it is not refactor-safe, i.e. your IDE will not modify that code in class A if you change the name of the FOO to something else. If you're just experimenting, then play on...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Map, something like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test 
{
    public Test() 
    {
        final B b = new B();
        final C c = new C();
        System.out.println(b.getFoo());
        System.out.println(c.getFoo());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Test();
    }
}

class A 
{
    private static final Map<String, String> values;

    static
    {
        values = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    public String getFoo() 
    {
        return (values.get("FOO"));
    }

    protected static void addValue(final String key,
                                  final String value)
    {
        values.put(key, value);
    }
}

class B extends A 
{
    static
    {
        addValue("FOO", "$HOME.DIR/lib/res/image1.png");
    }
}

class C extends A 
{
    static
    {
        addValue("FOO", "$HOME.DIR/lib/res/image2.png");
    }
}
```